# fancybox открывает картинку в самом низу страницы

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего fancybox может открывать изображение в самом низу страницы (не в окне, а просто в тексте).

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/asset/common/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <div id="photos">
                    <a href="/files/photo/12/4d9dae5336d817af05a509f6c9485650.png" rel="group" style=" text-decoration:none;" class="gallery">
                    <img src="/files/photo/12/min_4d9dae5336d817af05a509f6c9485650.png" style="width:98px; margin-right:15px;" alt="Офис">
                </a>
                            <a href="/files/photo/12/823241d72f5f45fa9c7a107f8511a6f8.jpg" rel="group" style=" text-decoration:none;" class="gallery">
                    <img src="/files/photo/12/min_823241d72f5f45fa9c7a107f8511a6f8.jpg" style="width:98px; margin-right:15px;" alt="Офис">
                </a>

                    <div class="clear" style="height: 11px"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.gallery").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

В консоли ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобралась, оказалось, неправильно подключался файл стилей.